# Is there a way to detect hover mechanism (or trackpad/mourse)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I currently have `@media (any-hover: hover)` condition in my css, and previously with `(hover: hover)`, but neither do what I want: **I would like to only enable hover event if a mobile device have some kind of hover mechanism (eg. trackpad, mouse but not limited) implanted.**

However, with `hover:hover` at least on iPad it doesn't stimulate the hover event at all (I know `hover` detects if the device's primary interaction supports hover), not even I have magic keyboard connected (which has a trackpad). Then I change to `any-hover` and this time the iPad stimulates hover even without any accessory connected, and is interact with touch.

Hence, is there's a way to detect if a device has hover-able device connected? Should I use `pointer: fine` or `pointer: coarse` to do this? Or is there a way to do so in JS? I don't want it simply detect if there's a mouse connected, but any kind of device with hover-like mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want something that does *not* match for normal iPads and *does* match if someone plugs a mouse into an iPad?

`pointer: fine` is usually enough, but you can get even more precise with `(any-hover: hover) and (pointer: fine)`. You really only want to enable hover content for devices that have fine-grained pointer control.

You can express this in JS as well:

```
let mql = window.matchMedia('(any-hover: hover) and (pointer: fine');
```

> Then I change to any-hover and this time the iPad stimulates hover even without any accessory connected, and is interact with touch.

That seems like a bug.

Comment: Thanks, an additional question, does iPad pointer use `fine` with Apple Pencil (and equivalent on android tablet), because that doesn't have any hover mechanism at least with first and 2nd gen.

Comment: So I just tested with your solution, it seems that apple consider the iPad pointer is a `coarse` pointer, and `@media (any-hover: hover) and (pointer: coarse)` together with the `pointer:fine` query would do the trick.

Comment: `pointer: coarse` will not match a desktop mouse. Try using `any-pointer: fine`

Comment: Leland, indeed desktop mouse would only match `fine`, that's why after my experiment I found `@media (any-hover: hover) and (pointer: coarse), (any-hover: hover) and (pointer: fine)` would work with both tablet (which match `coarse`) and PC.